# How to redirect to login page with server.session.timeout and we are not using springsecurity

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, session-timeout

We are developing an application using angularjs and springboot currently we are not using any session timeout so it closing by default after 30mins.

To make it as 2 mins, i have used server.session.timeout , but i would like to redirect to login page once time is completed.
Note : we are not using any spring security.

Could you provide your views on how to accomplish this using angularjs / springboot

Comment: I'm not familiar with the actions taken by server.session.timeout, but I would define some kind of flag server.session.timeout can set to false or true if the timeout is reached. In AngularJS you can "subscribe" to those flags and get immediately informed whenever it changes. You can then call a method which redirects your page to the login page.  

Please have a look at Oberservables and Subjects in Angular. I think this is what you're searching for...